# For two ideals $I$ and $J$ prove that $I(R/J)=(I+J)/J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, tensor-products

> Prove that $\displaystyle R/I \otimes_{R} R/J \cong R/(I+J)$ , where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

We have , $\displaystyle R/I \otimes R/J \cong \frac{(R/J)}{I(R/J)} \cong \frac{(R/J)}{(I+J)/J} \cong R/(I+J)$. Everything is okay other than the 2nd line.

> How $I(R/J)=(I+J)/J$ ?

I've stuck to prove this. Any hint. ?

Comment: It is probably $R/J$ instead of $R/I$ before the last $\cong$. And: $I(R/J)=I((R+J)/J)=(I+IJ+J)/J=(I+J)/J$.

Comment: Yes..You are right,That was a typo. Now fixed

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use the definition, it's obvious: an element of $I\cdot R/J$ is  the ideal of $R/J$ generated by $I$, so it is the set of finite sums of the form:
$$\Bigl\{\sum_k i_kr_k+J\bigm\vert i_k\in I, r_k\in R\Bigr\}.$$
Now, as $I$ is an ideal in $R$, the set of these finite sums u=is nothing but $I$ itself, whence the formula 
$$I\cdot R/J=(I+J)/J.$$
Note that, by the second isomorphism theorem,  the latter quotient is isomorphic to $I/I\cap J$.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the real question, but I will give other proof for your theorem:

Define $f:R/I \times R/J \to R/(I+J)$,

$(x \mod I, y \mod J) \to xy \mod(I+J)$.

By universal property, we get the linear map: $R/I \otimes R/J \to R/(I+J)$

Now we need the inverse function.

Observe that $\varphi:R \to R/I \otimes R/J$, $r \to r(1\otimes 1)$. Then $I+J \subset ker(\varphi)$. We conclude $\phi: R/(I+J) \to R/I \otimes R/J$ define as $\varphi$ is well-defined.

Now you can conclude existence of isomorphism.

Comment: Is $f$ well-defined?